# PowerBI - Use ODBC connector with connection string parameter

Tags: powerbi, odbc, huawei-cloud

I need to connect to an external Datasource through ODBC connector in PowerBI.

The ODBC connector, requires multiple parameters, from

- region
- ak/sk
- schema

I don't think is necessary to configure ONE ODBC connection per each desired connection (e.g. I want to connect to different schemas).

[image: ODBC connector configuration in Windows 11 ODBC Administrator Tool]

The connection string is in the form of:

```
jdbc:dli://dli.ap-southeast-2.myhuaweicloud.com/SECRET_PROJECT_ID?databasename=DESIRED_DATABASE;queuename=default;authenticationmode=aksk;servicename=dli;regionname=ap-southeast-2;accesskey=MY_AK;secretkey=MY_SECRET_SK;
```

I would like to avoid configuring some of the parameters on the ODBC admin, and pass it in the connection string parameters on PowerBI:

[image: PowerBI - Permissions panel]

Please, experts on ODBC and PowerBI, help me :).

**Additional information:**

- https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/devg-dli/dli_09_0128.html

**NOTE**: ODBC works, works on DBeaver